# Correct translation of Micah 5:1

Tags: commentaries, translation, micah

1 Samuel 23:23 speaks of 'thousands of Yehudah', Micah 5:1 also speaks of 'thousands of Yehudah', but then I noticed Zechariah 12:5-6 which speaks of 'princes/leaders of Yehudah'. I know there are two different roots in play, but these phrases are spelled with the same letters. Noticing this, I found it strange that Micah 5:1 was translated as thousands of Yehudah, because it takes Beit Lechem from Efratah and places it against a thousands of Yehudah, were there really thousand of cities in comparison to Beit-Lechem in Yehudah? Or should Micah 5:1 also be understood to refer to 'leaders of Yehudah', as the one comming from Beit-Lechem would also be a leader.

Answer (score 1):

[Micah 5:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16191/showrashi/true) is translated as

> וְאַתָּ֞ה בֵּֽית־לֶ֣חֶם אֶפְרָ֗תָה צָעִיר֙ לִֽהְיוֹת֙ בְּאַלְפֵ֣י
>   יְהוּדָ֔ה מִמְּךָ֙ לִ֣י יֵצֵ֔א לִֽהְי֥וֹת מוֹשֵׁ֖ל בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל
>   וּמוֹצָֽאֹתָ֥יו מִקֶּ֖דֶם מִימֵ֥י עוֹלָֽם:
>
> And you, Bethlehem Ephrathah-you should have been the lowest of the
>   clans of Judah-from you [he] shall emerge for Me, to be a ruler over
>   Israel; and his origin is from of old, from days of yore.

Rashi says

> you should have been the lowest of the clans of Judah: You should have
>   been the lowest of the clans of Judah because of the stigma of Ruth
>   the Moabitess in you.